# Cannot render embed code code using React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-parser

I am using React to render an html, javascript code from an API.
The api response is as below:

```
`<div class="infogram-embed" data-id="bc973e33-5e3e-4bf3-b587-9a6f16caf158" data-type="interactive" data-title="Konsumtionslån från Norden ökar">
```

`<script>!function(e,t,s,i){var n="InfogramEmbeds",o=e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],d=/^http:/.test(e.location)?"http:":"https:";if(/^/{2}/.test(i)&&(i=d+i),window[n]&&window[n].initialized)window[n].process&&window[n].process();else if(!e.getElementById(s)){var r=e.createElement("script");r.async=1,r.id=s,r.src=i,o.parentNode.insertBefore(r,o)}}(document,0,"infogram-async","https://e.infogram.com/js/dist/embed-loader-min.js");</script><div style="padding:8px 0;font-family:Arial!important;font-size:13px!important;line-height:15px!important;text-align:center;border-top:1px solid #dadada;margin:0 30px">`
`<a href="https://infogram.com/bc973e33-5e3e-4bf3-b587-9a6f16caf158" style="color:#989898!important;text-decoration:none!important;" target="_blank">Konsumtionslån från Norden ökar</a><br><a href="https://infogram.com" style="color:#989898!important;text-decoration:none!important;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Infogram</a></div>`

and using `htmlToReactParser.parse(block.html)` to parse the html content above using this library for react `require('html-to-react').Parser`

The service that the html code is given by api is from Infogram embed code.

There is suppose to be shown some graphs from that embed code, which are not showing in my case!

Comment: do you get any erros in browser console? maybe the script tags are nopt parsed by the parser due to security reasons

Comment: @NikosM. no errors, no warnings.

Comment: also the script tags are showing on the dom when i inspect from the chrome